# struggling to find next prime in R programming

Tags: java, r

I'm new to R programming and I am struggling to find the next prime number given some number x. I have tried the logic in Java and it works. So what I really did was to translate some Java code to R. So here is my Java version that works.

```
public static int nextPrime(int n) {
    int i,j;
    for( i= n+1;;i++) {
        for(j=2;j<i;j++) {
            if(i % j == 0)
                break;
            }
            if(j == i) {
            // System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

and here is my R version

```
nextPrime <- function(x) {
    i = x+1
        repeat {
            for(j in 2 : (i-1)) {
                if((i %% j) == 0 ) {
                    break
                }
                # j = j+1
                # print(j)
            }
        if( i == j){
            break
        }
        i = i+1
    }
    print(i)       
}
nextPrime(11)
```

Comment: What's the error you encounter?

Comment: Or what issue are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Java, but here is a function - while loop -  that gives you what you want.

```
f <- function(x){
  # @IsmailMüller
  temp <- x+1
  test <- 2:x

  # while temp is divisible by at least one precedent value (not prime)
  while( any( (temp %% test) == 0 ) ){
    # increase the value of temp by 1
    temp <- temp+1
  }
  temp
}
f(11)
```

Comment: Hi Ismail. I am expecting f(3) or f(5) or..f(anyprimenumber) to return that number itself. How do u handle in this existing code..

Answer (score 1):

Following your code, both are not same.

Replace

```
for(j in 2 : (i-1))
```

With

```
for(j in 2 : i)
```